# NXP arm microprocessor memory erase - no JTAG

Tags: microcontroller, arm, jtag, nxp

I am fiddling around with NXP LPC2368. Recently changed the PLL clock control registers, and as a result JTAG stopped working, so I am unable to program or erase the chip.

My question is, is there any way to erase the chip "manually", as in, non-programatically? Any way that dos not involve using JTAG.

Yes, I've searched the user manual, couldn't find the answer.

Answer (score 3):

1. **THE OBVIOUS METHOD** is to use the built in bootloader and [flashmagic] to erase it via the serial port. I'm guessing that you already considered and rejected this method, possibly because your board doesn't give you access to both the serial port pins and the boot control pin(s). The LPC2368 overview suggests the bootloader also works via USB. I didn't confirm.
2. **THE TIMING METHOD:** (Part of) the reason you can't get control via JTAG is that the aforementioned system bootloader always<sup>1</sup> runs after reset, no matter what the boot pin settings, and JTAG cannot get control until after that is finished. What you need (after a hardware reset) is for the JTAG controller to assert [TMS, I think] just *after* the system bootloader is finished, but *before* your code changes the problematic registers. If you keep trying to connect via JTAG, with random timing between that and your hardware reset button, you might fail 500 times and get lucky on the 501st.

Note 1: It has to run at least far enough to verify your "magic checksum"

Note 2: This would be better as a comment but I don't have rep points.

Comment: Yeah, the board is pretty restricted, no easy access to any UART except 3 (AFAIK flashmagic needs UART0?).

Comment: It is UART0 on the chips I've used.

Answer (score 2):

The LPC2368 has a ROM bootloader thats starts by pulling pin P2.10 LOW during and after reset (see UM10211 chapter 29.3). This mode allows you to connect your JTAG debugger to the chip.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that. Though, I tried pulling P2.10 LOW on power-up and reset but it still enters my user code (can confirm by observing GPIO states of my last loaded code still appearing).. I am kinda confused now.